# Selecting a NxM sub matrix from boost::MultiArray by variable

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, matrix, boost-multi-array

I have multiple NxM matrices and want to select one of them by a variable. My best guess was to use `boost::MultiArray` to create a NxMxP matrix an then select via third dimension.

I implemented it using array_view:

```
typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> threeDimMatrix;
typedef threeDimMatrix::index_range rangeDim;
threeDimMatrix hypotheses(boost::extents[nInputs][nStates][nChan]);
threeDimMatrix::array_view<2>::type hypothesesAdd =
     hypotheses[boost::indices[rangeDim(0,2)][rangeDim(0,2)][ IDX ] ];
```

Unfortunately I then want to continue my code with this matrix as a `boost::matrix` and don't know how to. Can I do something like a cast?

Or is it even possible without multi_array? Can I else somehow select a matrix via variable?

Comment: If you're treating it as a collection of matrices rather than a 3D matrix directly, why not just do something like std::deque<boost::matrix>? (Substitute an appropriate STL container for your needs).

Comment: Seems to not work: error: template argument 2 is invalid. Also tried: 
    std::deque<boost::numeric::ublas::matrix> hypothesesQue;

Comment: You need "std::deque<boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> >". Matrix is a template, not a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a 3 dimensional array, can't you just keep your Boost matrices as they are and have a mapper to them? Then no casts are necessary and you should not have any problems.

The mapper could be a basic array where the index will be your key, or use the C++ library [cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map).

Comment: thats what I was thinking to. But I don't know how to get to that. Any code snippet where I can see how it's working?

Comment: (Enter is apparently "add comment") Hope this reference will help you to create a map where T will be your boost:array

Comment: For now this seems to work. Gonna finish my code tomorrow. Thanks